# Outlook won't open after the latest Windows 10 Pro update

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, windows-update

This morning I updated Windows 10 Pro (64-bit) to build number 19041.388. But since the update, Outlook has been refusing to start up. All the other Office applications work without error. Only Outlook is behaving problematically. It crashes almost immediately with the following message in Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.13001.20384, time stamp: 0x5f05e3bb
Faulting module name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.13001.20384, time stamp: 0x5f05e3bb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000015c52a
Faulting process id: 0x31f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d65acc4ccf67dc
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
```

I ran first the offline, and then the online, version of the repair tool that comes with Office installer. Both reported that the problem had been fixed. (The online version even seemed to download Office all over again.) But Outlook still won't open--or rather, won't stay open for more than a few seconds.

What other steps can I take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run this `"%Programfiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.12827.20470`

Patch causing problems today.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute this from Windows + R and copy past this

```
"%Programfiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.12827.20470
```

This will update office and fix the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I have one machine working and one machine not working.

Try reverting to a prior version on the not working machine.

First, go to Office Account and disable Updates. You may need to go into Safe Mode if Outlook won't open.

Next, open an Admin Command Prompt and enter the following command:

```
`"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.13001.20266`
```

Now Office did not downgrade (it might for you) but it appears that simply turning Updates OFF works. My Outlook is running normally.

**Office Account, Updates, Disable Updates.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new symptom of Outlook crashing on launch is a known issue starting on 7/15/2020. As a workaround, you could temporarily use Outlook web mail or revert to an earlier version of Outlook. Besides, please keep an eye on the update from Microsoft.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1b1f952f-cb31-43d3-bf93-221b84080a70/outlook-office365-will-not-open-after-windows-update?forum=Office2016ITPro
For more information, pelase check this similar thread.